I'm getting different values for the calculation of voltage drop across parallel resistors than I am for the summed voltage drop. How do I fix this?
I'm getting different values for the calculation of voltage drop across parallel resistors than I am for the summed voltage drop. How do I fix this? The current on the 4ohm resistor is 0.5Amperes. When I calculate the summed voltage drop across the parallel resistors, I get a voltage of 2volts for the 4ohm resistor, and then set the other two resistors' voltage equal to the 4ohm resistor since they're parallel resistors, then solve for the current across both of them to get 0.25Amperes each for the two 8ohm resistors. However, the equivalent resistance from the parallel resistors should be 2ohms, and so with this current the voltage drop from the equivalent resistance should come to 2volts. This is much different from the sum of 6volts that we would get from summing the voltage drop across all three parallel resistors. 

The equivalent resistance is not the sum of the resistances. That's for resistors in series.

The voltage across each resistor, and the parallel combination, should all be the same (2 Volts as you calculated).  For parallel resistor circuits, like what you have shown, one does not sum the individual voltages, as this is not relevant here.  However, it does makes sense to sum the current through each resistor to get the total current flowing through that circuit, if that was needed (1.0 Amperes, in this case).
If the resistors were in series, then you would sum the individual voltage drops to get the total voltage drop across the circuit.

Got it. Thanks. I was a little bit confused about how it all worked out. Your explanation together with another one I just heard helped me understand the concept and application. Thanks again.
